# How to initialize a wrapper class using a parametrized base class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

How to parametrize initialisation of a class. For example, to wrap `BaseClass1` and `BaseClass2` it's possible to:

```
class BaseClass1:
    pass

class BaseClass2:
    pass

class Wrapper(BaseClass1):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def new_method(self):
        return 1

w = Wrapper()
```

How to parametrize it so that the base class can be chosen upon initialization?

For example, how to initialize the `Wrapper` class using:

```
w1 = Wrapper('BaseClass1')
w2 = Wrapper('BaseClass2')
```

or:

```
b1 = BaseClass1
w1 = Wrapper(b1)
b2 = BaseClass2
w2 = Wrapper(b2)
```

or:

```
w1 = Wrapper(BaseClass1)
w2 = Wrapper(BaseClass2)
```

Where the base class is a parameter?

The objective is to override/add additional methods to class instances.

**Update**

Thanks @Serge Ballesta for posting an answer, how to extend the answer so that the new methods have access to the base class attributes? For example:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 1

def Wrapper(x):
    class _wrap(x):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def new_method(self):
            return self.id
    return _wrap
```

Where `instance.new_method()` will return 1 in the below code:

```
instance = Wrapper(Base)()
instance.new_method()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically create a class at run time inside a function:

```
def Wrapper(x):
    class _wrap(x):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def new_method(self):
            return 1
    return _wrap
```

You can they use it normally:

```
W1 = Wrapper(BaseClass1)
W2 = Wrapper(BaseClass2)
w1 = W1()
w2 = W2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use metaclasses:

```
class BaseClass1:
    def d1(self):
        print(1)


class BaseClass2:
    def d2(self):
        print(2)


def make_class(base):
    return type('MyClass', (base,), {})


MyClass1 = make_class(BaseClass1)
MyClass2 = make_class(BaseClass2)

c1 = MyClass1()
c2 = MyClass2()

c1.d1()  # 1
c2.d2()  # 2
```

If you want to have a common attribute for generated class, you can use this:

```
def make_class(base):
    def new_method(...):
            ...
    return type('MyClass', (object, ),
            {'common_attr:1,
             'new_method': new_method})
```

Comment: `TypeError: a new-style class can't have only classic bases`

Comment: @Greg: If you're on Python 2, make the bases new-style either by explicitly inheriting from `object` (`class BaseClass1(object):`), or put `__metaclass__ = type` at the top of your module (before defining any classes) to make all classes defined from there on out implicitly new-style. On Python 3, only new-style classes exist, so none of that is necessary; Ramazan probably assumed you were on modern Python because you didn't tag or otherwise indicate a specific Python version.

Comment: @Greg may I ask why you still use Python 2?

Comment: @RamazanPolat it is not my decision or choice. Mainly due to other complex dependencies...

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you that worked! Where should the function definition for `new_method` as shown in the `Wrapper` class example (in my post) go?

Comment: @RamazanPolat Where should the function definition for new_method as shown in the Wrapper class example (in my post) go?